# Cannot evaluate errors on parameters validation--SpagoBI

Tags: spagobi

SpagoBi Report in server when reload after 5 mins or more
Showing the following error.

> Service Error: Cannot evaluate errors on parameters validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked the parameter on Server. there is some problem in Parameter Configuration on Server.